# How do I tell python to NOT print an item in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, feedparser, goose

My python script parses titles and links from multiple RSS feeds. I store those Titles in a list and I want to make sure I never print duplicates. How do I do that?

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
 from twitter import *
 from goose import Goose
 import feedparser
 import time
 from pyshorteners import Shortener
 import pause
 import newspaper

 dr = feedparser.parse("http://www.darkreading.com/rss_simple.asp") 
 sm =feedparser.parse("http://www.securitymagazine.com/rss/topic/2654-cyber-tactics.rss")



dr_posts =["CISO Playbook: Games of War & Cyber Defenses",
         "SWIFT Confirms Cyber Heist At Second Bank; Researchers Tie Malware Code to Sony Hack","The 10 Worst Vulnerabilities of The Last 10 Years",
         "GhostShell Leaks Data From 32 Sites In 'Light Hacktivism' Campaign",
          "OPM Breach: 'Cyber Sprint' Response More Like A Marathon",
        "Survey: Customers Lose Trust In Brands After A Data Breach",
       "Domain Abuse Sinks 'Anchors Of Trust'",
       "The 10 Worst Vulnerabilities of The Last 10 Years",
]

sm_posts = ["10 Steps to Building a Better Cybersecurity Plan"]

x = 1

while True:

    try:

        drtitle = dr.entries[x]["title"]
        drlink = dr.entries[x]["link"]
        if drtitle in dr_posts:
            x += 1
            drtitle = dr.entries[x]["title"]
            drtitle = dr.entries[x]["link"]
            print drtitle + "\n" + drlink
            dr_posts.append(drtitle)
            x -= 1
            pause.seconds(10)
        else:
            print drtitle + "\n" + drlink
            dr_posts.append(drtitle)
            pause.seconds(10)

        smtitle = sm.entries[x]["title"]
        smlink = sm.entries[x]["link"]
        if smtitle in sm_posts:
            x +=1
            smtitle = sm.entries[x]["title"]
            smtitle = sm.entries[x]["title"]
            print smtitle + "\n" + smlink
            sm_posts.append(smtitle)
            pause.seconds(10)
    else:
        print smtitle + "\n" + smlink
        sm_posts.append(smtitle)
        x+=1
        pause.seconds(10)



except IndexError:
    print "FAILURE"
    break
```

For the time being I only have it skipping entries. Which would be a problem because if there's another duplicate further down the line in the RSS feed, then I'll have even more duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the data structure [set](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), as its property of "uniqueness" will do the work for you. Essentially we can make your list a set and then the set a list again, which ensures your list is now populated with strictly unique values.

If you had a list l, then you could make it unique by

```
l = list(set(l))
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to print a repeating link you may use a [counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) or [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
sm_posts = defaultdict(int)
sm_posts[sm_links] += 1
print sm_posts.keys() #will print all the unique links
```

the good thing is that you can also get the count of repetitions of links by doing

```
sm_posts[sm_links]
>>> link_counts
```

try it.